# Python Glide mouse across screen

Tags: python, automation, bots, pyautogui

In a code like this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(100,200)
```

Or

```
Import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(100,150)
pytautogui.click()
```

The mouse cursor jumps to the specified location, how can i make the mouse curser glide instead of jumping to stimulate human mouse movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is taken directly from the documentation of `moveTo`:

> Normally the mouse cursor will instantly move to the new coordinates. If you want the mouse to gradually move to the new location, pass a third argument for the duration (in seconds) the movement should take. For example:

```
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(100, 200, 2)   # moves mouse to X of 100, Y of 200 over 2 seconds
```